# Laravel Swagger getting [Syntax Error] Expected Value, got '@'

Tags: php, laravel, swagger-php

I have written Swagger Annotations for a function in a Controller and I am getting error while generating swagger-ui code. Following is my code for annotation

```
/*** End of Annotation For deleteNote ***/
     /**
     * @OA\Delete(
     *     path="/api/delete-user-note/{note_id}",
     *     operationId="/api/delete-user-note/{note_id}",
     *     tags={"Patient Routes"},
     *      summary= "Delete Note",
     *      description = "Delete Note",
     *      @OA\Parameters(
     *         description="ID note to delete",
     *         in="path",
     *         name="note_id",
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *           type="integer",
     *           format="int64"
     *         )
     *     ),
```

When I run `php artisan l5-swagger:generate`
I am getting error
`[Syntax Error] Expected Value, got '@'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your Annotation. Please change your code with the following.
You need to replace `Parameters` with `Parameter`.

```
/*** End of Annotation For deleteNote ***/
     /**
     * @OA\Delete(
     *     path="/api/delete-user-note/{note_id}",
     *     operationId="/api/delete-user-note/{note_id}",
     *     tags={"Patient Routes"},
     *      summary= "Delete Note",
     *      description = "Delete Note",
     *      @OA\Parameter( //You need to replace Parameters with Parameter
     *         description="ID note to delete",
     *         in="path",
     *         name="note_id",
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *           type="integer",
     *           format="int64"
     *         )
     *     ),
```